# Subnet mask to variable DOS batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

To cut a long story short I need to get just the subnet mask on its own to a variable I can use in DOS

I can get the ip address on its own but need the mask also  I need to feed these values to other parts of the batch file

How would I even display the mask on its own?   I have searched about and nearest I came was the netsh command but could only dissplay information in bulk.

I need to isolate the subnet mask.

Hope someone has a idea?

Thanks

Confuseis

Comment: Welcome to SO! please note that SO is not a coding service, so you should try it on your own, and when problems arise, ask a specific question, sharing your effort, stating what you expect and showing what you actually receive; thanks... anyway, how do you get the IP?

Comment: How do you get the IP addr?

Comment: I got the IP address using    for /f "delims=[] tokens=2" %%a in ('ping -4 %computername% -n 1 ^ | findstr "[" ') do (set thisip=%%a)

Answer (score 2):

Let's use the output of `netsh int ip show config "Your connection name"`:

```
Configuration for interface "Your connection name"
    DHCP enabled:                         Yes
    IP Address:                           192.168.1.111
    Subnet Prefix:                        192.168.1.0/24 (mask 255.255.255.0)
    Default Gateway:                      192.168.1.1
    Gateway Metric:                       0
    InterfaceMetric:                      10
    DNS servers configured through DHCP:  192.168.1.1
    Register with which suffix:           Primary only
    WINS servers configured through DHCP: None
```

And parse the line with `mask` by extracting text between `(` and `)` and then getting the last token:

```c
@echo off
for /f "delims=() tokens=2" %%a in (
    'netsh int ip show config "Your connection name" ^| findstr /r "(.*)"'
) do for %%b in (%%a) do set mask=%%b
echo The netmask is %mask%
pause
```

To extract the mask bits value (`24` in this case) use `delims=/(` instead of `delims=()` in the code.

Comment: Thanks very much.   I'm going to research the For command more thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the answer below.  This will get the subnet mask to a variable, In this case  %subnet%

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims=:" %%A in ('ipconfig ^| find "Subnet"') do set subnet=%%A
set subnet=%subnet:~1%
echo %subnet%
```

Comment: Note: this code expects only one network connection and English system locale.