# cmd get subnet mask in slash notation

Tags: batch-file, cmd, subnet

I'm looking to get the subnet mask of a system in slash notation and assign it to a variable.
e.g.  /24 rather than  255.255.255.0

I have isolated the mask on its own as below.   But need this represented in bits /x   instead.

```
for /f "tokens=2,* delims=:" %%A in ('ipconfig ^| find "Subnet"') do set subnet=%%A
set subnet=%subnet:~1%
echo %subnet%
```

Thanks

Confuseis

Comment: Use [Subnet mask to variable DOS batch](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32403283) replacing `delims=()` with `delims=/(` and `"Your connection name"` with the actual connection name.

Comment: @wOxxOm .Wow. you answered this question two months ago for them.

Comment: Indeed wow. Now it makes sense as I thought the OP nick name is familiar. So the question is not only a duplicate but *almost* a doublepost.

Comment: I thought the question of attaining the /xx format instead of the 255.255.255.0  format was different enough from the original answer as to warrant a different question but the edit to that question worked and was far less complex that I envisioned.     "To extract the mask bits value (24 in this case) use delims=/( instead of delims=() in the code."       Much Obliged,  Thanks